# Playing videos from RSS feed in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have parsed the RSS feed http://www.teluguone.com/videosongs/videoSongsXml.php?cat_id=6 and displayed in listbox.When i click on a particular song automatically it should be navigated and start playing.But when i click on  a song it is navigating to other page but not playing.It was displaying "An error occured please try again".I am not understanding where the problem is.I have written the following code.No errors and warnings are rising.

please help me.i was trying on this from many days.

Maipage.Xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="videosongs.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:delay="clr-namespace:Delay;assembly=PhonePerformance"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Teluguone" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Videosongs" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="songsList"
            SelectionChanged="songsList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="130">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding songpic}" 
                               Grid.Column="0" 
                               Width="97" 
                               Height="125" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Margin="6"/>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,15,0,0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Height="60"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding songname}" 
                                       FontSize="30" />

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,50,0,0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding songdescr}" 
                                   Style='{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}'
                                   />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding songdate}" 
                                   Style='{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}'
                                   />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progress" Foreground="White" />
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

```
Mainpage.xaml.cs:
     public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
        {
            // Constructor
             public MainPage()
                {
            InitializeComponent();

        }  

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // is there network connection available
            if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
            return;
        }


        // start loading XML-data
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.teluguone.com/videosongs/videoSongsXml.php?cat_id=6", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(VideosongsDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

    }
   void VideosongsDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
            }
            else
            {
                // Deserialize if download succeeds
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Videosongs));
                Videosongs videosongs = (Videosongs)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
                songsList.ItemsSource = videosongs.Collection;
    }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    // selection in SongsdetailsList is changed
    private void songsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;

        if (listBox != null && listBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
             Songsdetails song = (Songsdetails)listBox.SelectedItem;
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(song);
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Videopage.xaml?songsongcode=" + song.songcode , UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Songsdetails.cs:
    public class Songsdetails

```
    {
        [XmlElement("songname")]
    public string songname { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songpic")]
    public string songpic { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songcode")]
    public string songcode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songdescr")]
    public string songdescr { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songtitletags")]
    public string songtitletags { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songmetatags")]
    public string songmetatags { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songmetadesc")]
    public string songmetadesc { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songdate")]
    public string songdate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("songurl")]
    public string songurl { get; set; }
```

Videosongs.cs:

```
 [XmlRoot("videosongs")]
    public class Videosongs
    {
        //[XmlElement("publisher")]
        //public string publisher { get; set; }

        //[XmlElement("publisherurl")]
        //public string publisherUrl { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("songsdetails")]
        public ObservableCollection<Songsdetails> Collection { get; set; }
```

Videopage.Xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="videosongs.Videopage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:extended="clr-namespace:MyToolkit.Controls;assembly=MyToolkit.Extended"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768" 
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Landscape" 
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

<StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="title" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40"></TextBlock>
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Height="411"  IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="10,0,78,0" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Videopage.Xaml.cs:

```
namespace videosongs
{
 public partial class Videopage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public Videopage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         // When page is navigated to set data context to selected item in list
         protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
           {
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred! Please verify your internet connection.");
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
            else
             {
            string video = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/+getsongcode()";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(video);
             this.webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(video));

            }
        }

        }
```

Anybody please help.Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you're having internet both in your emulator and the device when you're testing?

Comment: ya i was sure i have internet connection in both.When i run this app i was not getting any errors and warnings also.But in output windows i get a message.Cannot find or open pdb files.